# Galaxy S III (3) location manager accuracy

Tags: android, coordinates, galaxy, locationmanager

I developed an App that is pairing users based on locations (for both android and iOS devices).
In my iOS development everything went perfectly well.
On the other hand, for my android development I used the "location.getAccuracy()" method to stay in the right range.

Unfortunately, for Galaxy S3 devices, the Accuracy is the same to other devices but the coordinates are completely different!
I've debugged my code on several devices and the problem did not repeat itself on every device but the Galaxy S3 devices..

Does anyone know what may be the problem??

Comment: what do you mean, "complete different"? It says you're in antarctica, while standing in downtown new york?

Comment: It has an offset of about 10km...
But galaxy s2/s4 are fine.